# In Python tests, how to make sure only some methods/attributes are invoked?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm starting to use unittests.patch, Mock, etc.

This is not the best example, but I think it serves the purpose:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

class A:

    def good_fun(self):
        return "complex operation"

    def bad_fun(self):
        print("Oh no!")

def test(mocker):

    with patch(f'{__name__}.A.good_fun', return_value=3) as mocked:
        a = A()
        result = a.good_fun()
        #a.bad_fun()

        assert result == 3
        mocked.assert_called_once()
```

This tests is passing the assertions. However, in the future someone will mistakenly uncomment the `a.bad_fun()` method (which is not intended). How can make sure the test will break if that happens?

I was looking for some way to say "only pass the test if only the methods/attributes' I patches were called. Anything else should through an error.

Comment: Can't you mock `bad_fun()` and have the mock raise an exception as a `side_effect` when it's called? Or alternatively, assert that the bad_fun mock has not been called?

Comment: I can. But I was thinking of general case, with multiple methods. Do I have to mock every one of the methods? For every class?